# Android: how to layout the button so the text looks like the one in screenshot?

Tags: android, layout, text, button, alignment

[image: button]

Please have a look at the screenshot above, the string for the text is "DELETE SELECTED\nMESSAGES" if I use wrap_content for width/height of its parent linearlayout, the text would look like:

DELETE

SELECTED

MESSAGES

(without line space between each word)

if I use match-parent for the button's width, it will be stretched to match its parent, which is not what I want. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

the layout of the button:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/solid_grey_btm_rounded">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/delete_selected_messages"
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete_message"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_grey_selector">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am working on Android 2.3.3 API Level 10, I was testing on a Motorola Milestone(the one with real keyboard)

Comment: It works for me. Maybe it would be helpful if you say which Android version you are using and what Phone

Comment: Probably you can use fixed width .. and can you send your layout-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my setting the button's layout_width and layout_height to "match_parent" or "fill_parent", also, added margin to make the button not fullfil its parent, added padding to make the text narrower.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:minLines="2"`, this should help.

Comment: I tried it, with the new line character in the string, it still shows three lines, and if I remove the new line character, it is just one line and stretched the width of the button.